# Create variable based on URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Let's say I have a website at www.hostname.com/example. I would like to create a page, that generates based off of any extension of the original url. For example, I would have a page called setup.php. If someone were to go to www.hostname.com/example/xyz, it would load setup.php, and utilize xyz as a variable to customize setup.php. Is this possible? I have tried searching google, but have found no results. Any thoughts?

Comment: Here you need to use `.htaccess`, neither `php` nor `javascript`.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Is it just a boolean value I need to change?

Comment: No, it is a special file where you place commands to the server. Search `rewrite rule htaccess` in google to find it out.

Comment: This should introduce you to what you need to do: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: Here is a good explanation for beginners: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-basic-examples.html

Answer (score 1):

Take for example the url `http://www.noticeeverything.com/news/`. You could grab just the string "news" like this:

```
var url = window.location.href; 
var str = url.substring(32, 36); 
console.log(str);
```

Or, without having to determine the index of the substring you want:

```
var url = window.location.href; 
var str = url.replace('http://www.noticeeverything.com/news/', 'news'); 
console.log(str);
```

Or, if you don't know what the url is specifically, but expect it to follow the same pattern (i.e. 'http://www.something.com/something/'):

```
var pattern = /[a-z]+/; 
var url = window.location.href;
var newString = url.replace("http://www.", '').replace(pattern, '').replace('.com/', '').replace('/', '');
console.log(newString);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make a file called `.htaccess` and place it in the main directory. Then put this code in it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ setup.php?data=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now whatever url you open, the file `setup.php` will be executed and you can get the requested data with the `$_GET['data']` variable. For example:

```
<?php
$data = $_GET['data'];
if($data === 'xyz') {
echo "<b>xyz</b> is requested!";
include "xyz.php";
}
else {
echo "error 404: page not found";
}
?>
```

Comment: I think this is right, except I want the data _after_ the first folder. So if I was at `servername.com/folder/xyz`, it would return `xyz` to the setup.php file.